# How to make dynamic drop down list?

Tags: excel, list, dynamic

I'm trying create dynamic drop down list in MS Excel O365. I've made 2 tables in 2 different sheets. In below are table in "Workers" sheet:

[image]

And in "Order_status" sheet:

[image]

As for as these tables are concerned i inserted that data manualy. Now i'd like create dynamic drop down which in "ID_Worker" i get data from "Workers" sheet and when i select ID_WORKER in "Order_status" sheet:

a) not only displays ID_WORKER, FNAME, LNAME (For example 1 Paul Boy)

b) Automatically writes data into ID_WORKER, FNAME and LNAME columns.

I've done dynamic drop down list which it selects only ID_Workers from "Workers" sheet. And that source formula i've written like this:

```
=Workers!$A$2:$A$1048576
```

I'll explain what i'd like to do (In example):

1) In "Order status" are 3 columns: "ID_WORKER", "FNAME", "LNAME" but the data in this sheet are empty.

[image]

2) When i click on cell in "ID_WORKER" column then it shows like this: "1 Paul Boy".

3) Then i select value in this column later in "FNAME" and "LNAME" column should be written automatically: In "FNAME" is "Paul" and in "LNAME" should be "Boy".

I was searching for any solutions but i have still no clue what to do? Any ideas? Thx for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

1. Create a table with workers and name it "tblWorkers". For example purposes table range is `Sheet1 A1:C5`.
2. Select the range you want to import the drop down list with the ID_WORKERS, Go Data, Data Tools tab, Data Validation, Allow:List & Source: `=INDIRECT("tblWorkers[ID_WORKERS]")`. 
   For example purposes range used is `Sheet1 E2:E5`.
3. Formula for:

   FNAME:`=IF(E2<>"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,tblWorkers[#All],COLUMN(tblWorkers[FNAME]),FALSE),"Not Matched"),"")` For example purposes range is `Sheet1 F2:F5`

   LNAME:`=IF(E2<>"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,tblWorkers[#All],COLUMN(tblWorkers[LNAME]),FALSE),"Not Matched"),"")` For example purposes range is `Sheet1 G2:G5`

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Hmm... In that image which you sent is made in 1 sheet?

Comment: Yes, the image is from sheet 1

Comment: maybe right but is it possible to create table in 1-st sheet and then create drop down list in 2-nd sheet importing data from table in 1-st sheet?

Comment: yes is easy, follow the example given above and you will achieve it.

Comment: As for as drop down list concerned can i import with  "ID_WORKERS", "FNAME" and "LNAME"?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? In your question you mention that you create a drop down list with IDs `I've done dynamic drop down list which it selects only ID_Workers from "Workers" sheet.` . try to keep it simple to understand the whole concept.

Comment: Ok, but I'd like to create this with ID's, "FNAME" 's, "LNAME" 's too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194421/discussion-between-error-1004-and-prochu1991).

Comment: Ok i've made it with ID drop down list as you suggested and it works fine. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the field ID_Worker in sheet "Order_status" as a key, and lookup values of FNAME & LNAME from the "Workers" table.

Let's say your structure is as below:
Sheet "Workers"
Cell A1: 1, B1: Paul, C1: Boy
Cell A1: 2, B1: Adam, C1: John
Cell A1: 3, B1: Martin, C1: Ricky
Cell A1: 4, B1: Adam, C1: King

You already have your dropdown in field ID_Worker, sheet "Order_status" (btw the way you're doing it will cause alot of blanks, best to limit it referencing to the total rowcount)

Input the formula into cell b2, sheet "Order_status":=iferror(vlookup($A2,Workers!$A:$C,2,0)) drag the formula down

Repeat the same for cell c2:=iferror(vlookup($A2,Workers!$A:$C,3,0)) drag the formula down

Comment: Maybe it's a good point but still i'll select in drop down list only "ID_WORKER". In this drop down list i'd like to display for example (1 Paul Boy).

Comment: Ah, then you'd need to use a helper column. i.e. in Cell D2 of sheet "Workers", input the formula:=A2&" "&B2&" "&C2, and drag the formula down. In your drop down reference use =Workers!$D$2:$D$1048576 instead of =Workers!$A$2:$A$1048576

Comment: Sorry, to add on, so that you would get the FNAM & LNAME, you would need to amend the formula I had proposed above from =iferror(vlookup(LEFT($A2,SEARCH(" ",$A2)-1),Workers!$A:$C,2,0)) and =iferror(vlookup($A2,Workers!$A:$C,3,0)) to =iferror(vlookup(LEFT($A2,SEARCH(" ",$A2)-1),Workers!$A:$C,3,0))

Answer (score 0):

Select a cell where you want to create the drop-down list.
Go to Data –> Data Tools –> Data Validation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Ot3.png)

Comment: Well, but which version of MS Office do you have? Is it not a coincidence libre office?