# VBA Add data validation to B and C if value in A using "loop"

Tags: excel, vba, loops, validation

trying to avoid having a large file size by having data validation in every cell and changing from key cells but if value is added in Cell A2 add data validation in Cell B2 with my list. I have the code below working but using selection.

Any ideas how I can have it so every time a value is added to a cell in A data validation be added to B2 with one list and C2 with another list? Or would that just slow the sheet down. Ideally don’t want to have data validation in Bx and Cx unless there is a value in column Ax. Appreciate the help in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'if a value is entered in Ax then Bx will get data validation
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim MyList(5) As String
    MyList(0) = "try"
    MyList(1) = 2
    MyList(2) = "again"
    MyList(3) = 4
    MyList(4) = 5
    MyList(5) = 6

    'want to change to if value in Cell Ax then do data validation, instead of if selected
    Set KeyCells = Range("A2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then

        With Range("B2").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")

            'want to add a second data validation in cell C2, or Cxx if can loop
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437815/how-to-make-dynamic-drop-down-list) might show you a way to do this *without* needing to use any VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this? It will run whenever column A is changed and contents is not empty.

You might want to add a check that multiple cells are not changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'if a value is entered in Ax then Bx will get data validation
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim MyList(5) As String
MyList(0) = "try"
MyList(1) = 2
MyList(2) = "again"
MyList(3) = 4
MyList(4) = 5
MyList(5) = 6

If Target.Column = 1 and target.row >2 Then 'column A3 down
    If Len(Target) > 0 Then 'not empty
        With Target.Offset(, 1).Validation 'column B
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
        End With
        With Target.Offset(, 2).Validation 'column C
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
        End With
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you @sjr , this has worked - haven't read into how it works exactly, but appreciate it. Quick question, how would I get this to start from A3 onwards for example? Thanks again

Comment: OK good, can you accept the answer please I'll update it shortly when I have a moment.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about this but just amended the code above.

Comment: Hi @SJR, thanks again for you help with this - i tried to amend the code but it doesnt seem to be working. the amend I was hoping to make was to be if there is a value in B8 then add validation in i8 and K8 etc going down. but not sure where i've gone wrong

Comment: `If Target.Column = 1` restricts changes to column A so you need to amend that and the offset(s).